# Error in Audit Trail in MS Access VBA code

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I created an database in Microsoft Access which contains employee data (Name, Division, Manager, etc.) + a form to enter and edit data in the Employee Database. Next thing I did was to create an audit trail to track the changes I do.

For that I created a module called "Audit Trail" using VBA code. Also I connected it to the form through "Before Update" event procedure. But I am getting below error when I make a change or created a new profile.

[image]

Can someone help to find out what I am missing?

**Audit Trail Module**

```
Option Compare Database 
Public Function AuditChanges(RecordID As Double, UserAction As String) 
    On Error GoTo auditerr 
 
    Dim DB As Database 
    Dim rst As Recordset 
    Dim clt As Control 
    Dim UserLogin As String 
 
    Set DB = CurrentDb 
    Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("select * from Audit_Trail", adOpenDynamic) 
 
    UserLogin = Environ("Username") 
 
    Select Case UserAction 
        Case "New" 
            With rst 
                .AddNew 
                ![DateTime] = Now() 
                !UserName = UserLogin 
                !FormName = Employee_Master_Data_Input 
                !Action = UserAction 
                !RecordID = Employee_Master_Data_Input(EmpID).Value 
                .Update 
                .MoveNext ' Move to the next record 
                 
            End With 
             
         Case "Delete" 
            With rst 
                .AddNew 
                ![DateTime] = Now() 
                !UserName = UserLogin 
                !FormName = Employee_Master_Data_Input 
                !Action = UserAction 
                !RecordID = Employee_Master_Data_Input(EmpID).Value 
                .Update 
                .MoveNext ' Move to the next record 
                 
            End With 
 
        Case "Edit" 
            For Each clt In Employee_Master_Data_Input 
                If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox _ 
                 Or clt.ControlType = acComboBox) Then 
                 If Nz(clt.Value) <> Nz(clt.OldValue) Then 
                        With rst 
                            .AddNew 
                            ![DateTime] = Now() 
                            !UserName = UserLogin 
                            !FormName = Employee_Master_Data_Input 
                            !Action = UserAction 
                            !RecordID = Employee_Master_Data_Input(EmpID).Value 
                            !FieldName = clt.ControlSource 
                            !OldValue = clt.OldValue 
                            !NewValue = clt.Value 
                            .Update 
                            .MoveNext ' Move to the next record 
                             
                        End With 
                    End If 
                End If 
            Next clt 
    End Select 
 
    rst.Close 
    DB.Close 
    Set rst = Nothing 
    Set DB = Nothing 
 
    Exit Function 
 
auditerr: 
    ' MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error" 
    Exit Function 
 
End Function
```

**Before Update Event Procedure**

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Double) 
    If Me.NewRecord Then 
 
    Call AuditChanges("RecordID", "New") 
Else 
    Call AuditChanges("RecordID", "Edit") 
     
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: You have defined your `Form_BeforeUpdate` routine wrong: it needs to be `Cancel As Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is a compiler error and has nothing to do with all your Audit Trail code.

The definition of Event routines are defined by VBA. It follows the rule ObjectName + underscore + EventName, eg Form_BeforeUpdate. Certain Event routines get a predefined number of parameters.

The BeforeUpdate-Routine expects one parameter of type `Integer` named "Cancel". It serves the purpose to cancel the update (you need to set it to True or 1). Those parameters are called by Reference, so they must match what the VBA runtime expects (because there is no chance of an implicit conversion).

What you did is you changed the type of the parameter to `Double`, and that doesn't match what VBA expects. Therefore you get the error from the compiler saying that is doesn't match.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer) 
    If Me.NewRecord Then 
        Call AuditChanges("RecordID", "New") 
    Else 
        Call AuditChanges("RecordID", "Edit")  
    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to what was said before: your procedure will not work for new created records. When you execute your audit trail in the BeforeUpdate event of the form, the data is not already written to the table and cannot be accessed with a record set. You need to pick the data from the fields in the form instead.

Or you use the AfterUpdate event to get the data, e.g. by using the ID of the new created record. This would have the positive effect that you just take the data which are really saved because in the BeforeUpdate event the saving of the new data can still be cancelled and then you have an audit trail for non existing data.